Blazor WASM authentication not properly logging out Google user
I have followed this Microsoft guide.
I have created a brand new Blazor WebAssembly Standalone app. For Authentication, I choose "Individual Accounts", and I also include the sample pages. This gives me a project that is almost ready to use OIDC, and all I have to do is update the appsettings.json file with my own configuration from Google. Here are my values:
{
  "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://accounts.google.com/",
    "ClientId": "***.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7029/authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:7029/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "id_token"
    }
}

Logging in works, but logging out only works partially. If I refresh the page, it will log me in again. What am I missing here, and what must I do in order to let the user choose when to log back in again?

The "authentication/logout" only clear the local state but doesn't end the google provider session. You could try a workaround to visit "https://accounts.google.com/logout" to end the session.
LoginDispaly.razor
@inject IJSRuntime js
...

<script>
    async function LogoutGoogle(){
        var new_window=window.open("https://accounts.google.com/logout");
        setTimeout(() => {
            new_window.close();
        }, 2000);

    }
</script>

@code{
    public async Task BeginLogOut()
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("LogoutGoogle");
        Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout");
    }
}

